# Caching Computations in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a canonical way to reuse computations from a previously-supplied placeholder in TensorFlow? My specific use case:

- supply many inputs (using one placeholder) simultaneously, all of which are fed through a network to obtain smaller representations
- define a loss based on various combinations of these smaller representations
- train on one batch at a time, where each batch uses some subset of the inputs, *without recomputing the smaller representations*

Here is the goal in code, but which is defective because the same computations are carried out again and again:

```
X_in = some_fixed_data
combinations_in = large_set_of_combination_indices
for combination_batch_in in batches(combinations_in, batch_size=128):
    session.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: X_in, combinations: combination_batch_in})
```

Thanks.

Comment: Also, I'll need to cache X because the gradients that flow back from training will depend on X. (I'd edit my post but see no "edit" option right now.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The canonical way to share computed values across sess.Run() calls is to use a `Variable`. In this case, you could set up your graph so that when the Placeholders are fed, they compute a new value of the representation that is saved into a Variable. A separate portion of the graph reads those Variables to compute the loss. This will not work if you need to compute gradients through the part of the graph that computes the representation. Computing those gradients will require recomputing every Op in the encoder.

Comment: So you think there's no way to do it the "right" way, which would be to do one forward pass, cache those results, and compute gradients using those cached results?

Comment: As far as I know, you would need to implement your own version of tf.gradients that knows how to re-use values stored in Variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of thing that should be solved automatically with CSE (common subexpression elimination). Not sure what the support in TensorFlow right now, might be kind of spotty, but there's `optimizer_do_cse` flag for Graph options which is defaulting to false, and you can set it to true using GraphConstructorOptions. Here's a [C++ example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc#L500) of using GraphConstructorOptions (sorry, couldn't find a Python one)

If that doesn't work, you could do "manual CSE", ie, figure out which part is being needlessly recomputed, factor it out into separate Tensor, and reference that tensor in all the calculations.